# coldfusion application multi instance - synch application variables

Tags: coldfusion

I am working with a shared server running dual instances of CF10.  My application stores some functions in application variables and it is very important that both instances get refreshed at the same moment when the functions are updated.

The question then is this: Do both instances get updated when the OnApplicationStart() function is run?  This would be the only way to ensure proper code synchronization across instances.

I've not been able to find any reference to this and seem to be getting ambiguous results from the server.

Thanks for any shared knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ColdFusion instance can contain multiple applications.
Each application can contain multiple application and session variables.

The same code base can be run on multiple instances, even as multiple individual applications on the same instance.

When you restart Instance1, only the application(s) on that instance will pick up any code changes related to application or session variables. Therefore, you have to restart all instances on the same server to pick up these changes.

If you need a value to be accessible across all instances by multiple applications on the same physical server, then consider creating a variable in the `SERVER` scope.

If you set a variable like this `<cfset server.foo = "hello"`, then any application in any instance across the same physical (or virtual) server can access that variable. This would avoid having to restart all of the instances. Just update the function, then run a one-time script to reset the variable.

As of ColdFusion 9, you can opt to define this variable inside of the `onServerStart()` method of Application.cfc. This will make sure it's available whenever the whole server is restarted.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. That's exactly the information I needed.  By using the server scope I can keep the apps in synch.  Somehow, use of this scope has been lost on me. I appreciate the education!